# How to create custom nameserver that points to another name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, amazon-route53

Example I use amazon Route 53

Amazon gives me DNS such as

```
ns-111.awsdns-36.net
ns-222.awsdns-13.org
ns-333.awsdns-53.co.uk
ns-444.awsdns-20.com
```

But I want to create my own custom nameserver alias, such as...

```
ns1.mydomain.com -point to-->  ns-111.awsdns-36.net
ns2.mydomain.com -point to-->  ns-222.awsdns-13.org
ns3.mydomain.com  -point to-->  ns-333.awsdns-53.co.uk
ns4.mydomain.com -point to -> ns-444.awsdns-20.com
```

I would then add these custom name server to my registry.

Is this possible?

Comment: Route 53 doesn't currently support vanity / branded name servers.

Answer (score 5):

No, you *really* don't want to do this. Nameservers mentioned in NS records are not allowed to resolve to CNAMEs, so you will have to create glue records that point to amazon's IP addresses. Which they can change at any time, breaking your domain completely.

Answer (score 2):

AWS now allows this.

- In AWS, create a hosted zone.
- Get the IPs of each name server (dig ns-1954.awsdns-52.co.uk - > 5.5.5.5)
- Create/Register your 4 name servers with your registrar
- Each domain should point to the aws ip (ns1.example.com -> 5.5.5.5)
- Next change the name server that the domain itself is pointing to. Use your new ones (ns1.example.com and so on)
- In AWS, edit the NS record set. Delete the 4 aws name servers and put yours (ns1.example.com and so on)